# How to identify the last git merge into master?

Tags: git

I'm trying to identify the last merge into my master git branch, but the output of `git log` makes no sense.

The very last commands I ran were `git checkout master; git merge staging`, yet if I run `git log`, the first entry reads:

```
Merge branch 'staging' into DEVBRANCH-123
```

This is quite bewildering. Why does the merge into my master branch not mention the master branch, but instead a completely unrelated branch? Searching all of my git logs, nothing actually mentions the master branch. Why is this?

Comment: git merge staging means your merging your branch to the master or use gitk if you have it to see the git tree?

Answer (score 2):

If `git merge` did a "fast forward" instead of actually doing a merge, this leaves no trace in the graph.  It *does* leave traces in reflogs, and you can use these to discover them after the fact—but reflog entries eventually expire, wiping away the traces.

The `git log` command uses the graph to show you each commit, so if there is no trace of the fast-forward-not-a-merge "merge", it does not show you the fast-forward-not-a-merge "merge".  By default, `git log` ignores reflogs entirely (for good reason: the reflog is mainly intended for mistake-recovery and showing it would normally make the view even worse).

You probably should have done `git merge --no-ff`; see the last section below.  You can still do that, by finding (via the reflog) where `master` pointed before Git did its fast-forward operation.

#### Understanding real merges

"Fast forward" is one of the more confusing parts of Git.  To understand when and why Git can do a fast-forward, we need to look at how Git implements branching and what branch names really are/do, and how merge works.

A branch name, like `master` or `staging`, is just a short, human-readable name that stands in for one single commit.  This commit is the *tip* commit of a branch.  When we make a *new* commit, Git adds the commit to the tip of the *current branch* (whose name is stored in `HEAD`) and then makes that branch *name* point to the new tip.  The new tip commit, in turn, points back to what *was* the tip just a moment ago, before we added the new commit:

```
... <-F <-G   <-- branch
```

becomes:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <-- branch
```

Each commit "points back" to its immediate ancestor: its *parent* commit.  This gives Git the ability to follow the history of commits, which is made up of those commits themselves.  Commit `H` contains the ID of commit `G`; commit `G` contains the ID of `F`; and so on back to the very first commit (probably `A`), which has *no* parent, because it was the very first commit.

To get started in this history-following, Git needs the branch name, which "points to" (contains the ID of) the current tip.

When you create a new branch and develop on it, the commits themselves create the branch-y part of the graph.  Let's start with:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
```

and then create a new branch:

```
A--B--C   <-- master, branch (HEAD)
```

and then add a new commit:

```
A--B--C
```

A--B--C   <-- master
          \
           D   <-- branch (HEAD)

Now that we have two branch names (`master` and `branch`) we need to know *which one we're using*, hence the `(HEAD)`.  That's the branch that changes, to point to the new commit, when we *make* the new commit.

Now, suppose we have a bunch of different commits on two different branches, starting from some common starting point:

```
...--C--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
      \
       D--E--F   <-- branch
```

and we run `git merge branch`.  Git will find the common starting point `C`.  This is the *merge base*.

Git will now look to see "what we did" (`git diff --find-renames <commit-C> <commit-H>`, and "what they did" (`git diff --find-renames <commit-C> <commit-F>`.  The merge action, *to merge* as a verb, *combines these changes*.

Whatever we did to some files from `C`, Git tries to take our changes.  Whatever they did to files from `C`, Git tries to take their changes.  If neither of us changed some files from `C`, Git just carries the files forward.  If we both touched the *same* files, Git has to combine those changes in those files (and we might get a merge conflict).  If all goes well, though, Git now makes a new commit:

```
...--C--G--H---M   <-- master (HEAD)
      \       /
       D--E--F   <-- branch
```

The new commit goes on the current branch as usual, so that `master` points to the new tip; but this new tip commit has a special property: it has *two* parents, not just the usual one.  The *first* parent is the usual one, the previous tip of `master`.  The second parent is the tip of the other branch.

This commit is a *merge commit*.  It's like any other commit—it has a log message, usually something kind of useless like `merge branch 'branch'`, and an author name and email and time-stamp, and it records as its snapshot all the merged files.  But it's a special kind of commit: a two-parent commit.  This is a *merge commit*, using the word *merge* as an adjective.  We often shorten it even more: it is *a merge*, merge-as-a-noun.

#### Understanding fast-forward

Now that we know how a normal or "real" merge works, let's look at when Git can and does do a fast-forward instead.

Suppose that, instead of:

```
...--C--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
      \
       D--E--F   <-- branch
```

we just have:

```
...--C    <-- master (HEAD)
      \
       D--E--F   <-- branch
```

If we now run `git merge branch`, Git needs to combine all the changes we made on `master` since commit `C`, with all the changes they made on `branch` since commit `C`.  But wait, `master` *is* commit `C`.  The diff from `C` to `C` is going to be *empty!*  There's no need for merge-as-a-verb after all.  We can just make the name `master` point *directly to commit `F`*!

```
...--C
      \
       D--E--F   <-- master (HEAD), branch
```

This is a *fast-forward* operation.  Git makes no new commit, it just moves the label `master` forward, as fast as possible, across the chain of commits to the new branch tip.  Now `master` and `branch` point to *the same* commit and we can toss out the kink in the graph:

```
...--C--D--E--F   <-- master (HEAD), branch
```

Since `git log` is going to look at the graph, starting from the current branch tip (the `HEAD`), and we didn't make any new commit, we'll just view the commits starting from `branch`, which after all points to the same commit.

(The reason you're seeing a merge at `staging` is that the tip of `staging` is itself a merge—a commit with two parents.  This is the noun form of "merge", made because Git had to make one.)

#### What if you don't want a fast-forward?

You can prohibit `git merge` from using a fast-forward non-merge operation: just give it `--no-ff` as a command line option.  Git will then see that it *could* do a fast forward, but won't do it: it will make a new merge commit, with author and timestamp and log message.  The new commit's source code will come from the other branch tip, and the new commit will be a merge commit, with two parents:

```
...--C---------M    <-- master (HEAD)
      \       /
       D--E--F   <-- branch
```

In general, some merges *should* be done with `--no-ff`.  Merges from a staging branch into a master or release branch tend to be like this.

To undo a fast-forward, start by seeing if you can find out where the branch name pointed before the fast-forward.  In this case:

```
git reflog master
```

will show you where `master` pointed over time, as far back as your `master` reflog entries go anyway.  (Reflog entries stick around, by default, for at least 30 days, and at least 90 days for some cases, so you should have plenty of time here.)

Note that it's important that no *new* commits have been added to the branch since the fast-forward, since we're going to "rewind" things.  Let's say, for instance, that the reflog shows that `master` pointed to commit `C` earlier.

You can now use `git reset --hard <hash-id-of-C>` to move the current branch ("read `HEAD` to get the branch name" => `master`) so that it points to the same place it pointed-to before.  The `--hard` here means "wipe out the contents of the work-tree and staging-area, replacing them with the commit we moved to" (so don't do this unless those are all clean as well).  The end result is that you're back to the situation as it was before you did the fast-forward merge in the first place.  (Well, we can hope that `staging` did not acquire new commits; or if it did, there are further workarounds.)

Now you can run `git merge --no-ff staging` and force a real merge, and get the graph we drew for the `--no-ff` case.

Answer (score 0):

See what happend using this command:

```
git reflog
```

And all history tree:

```
git log --graph
```